# analysis of memory issue

Tags: java, grails, out-of-memory

EDIT -- so looked at Cache#15 and MemoryStore#9 in JVisualVM.  Turns out it is the query cache.  Hopefully dropping a cache configuration in conf that limits the query cache to less than 10k items (the default) will solve this...

---

We have a Grails application (v1.2.0) deployed on tomcat 6x.  Experienced an OOM crash.  Got the heap dump and started analyzing it in JVisualVM.  This is what I am seeing
[image]

and this
[image]

so lots of ehcache stuff, and definitely lots of byte and char arrays.  I have tried googling around 'grails memory leak ehcache' but nothing definitive is coming up.  Has anyone seen any issues like this or have any insights into what can be causing this?  Could it be a misconfigured ehcache?

We are using various plugins(acegi, quartz, mail, background-thread), all the the latest versions FOR grails version 1.2.0.

EDIT - some more info

starting tomcat with the following

```
-verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -d64 -server -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
```

and the error is

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Interestingly, we used to get perm gen space related errors, but when i updated to the Java configuration shown above, the permgen space errors went away.

Comment: How much memory are you giving to the heap and PermGen?

Comment: Do you have the EHCache monitor hooked up? that much memory would probably relate to a miss configuration of EHCache. Look to see if there is a certain cache which could be storing too much. Maybe set a maximum number of elements, and TTL for the elements of the cache.

Comment: @sean we definitely use the cache in the GORM mapping, but don't have a centralized ehcache config. maybe that is it.  Would the default TTL be forever?  Would it just keep caching objects over and over?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I have been inactive for a few days. Based on the documentation, it does appear that the default timetolive is set to 0 (never expire). Aside from the TTL, you will want to look at the MaxElementsInMemory setting. By default, this is set to Integer.MAX_SIZE. So if you havent set either value you could be dealing with alot of data in your cache. read here for more of the values http://ehcache.org/documentation/configuration.html

Comment: @sean, yeah it was the cached queries.  Ive dropped a custom ehcache in and things are good so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is normal to have lots of strings and char[]'s. I would try to correct the ehcache configuration... obviously you cache to much. There are options that dump the cache to the disk, maybe this is solution for you.

EDIT: The PermGen goes away because of `-XX:MaxPermSize=256m`, which is pretty much.

Comment: would not configuring ehcache cause it to recache instances, or allow the cache to grow indefinitely?

Comment: Depends on how you configure it. And I assumed you will restart the server after configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You could be running out of perm space, not heap.

Log your GC to a file and link, and post back your JVM args.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Grails 1.2.0 or 1.2.5 (latest 1.2.x)? Newest stable is 1.3.6.. I assume the problem is misconfigured ehcache though.

Comment: 1.2.0.  I am going to try and add an ehcache.xml to conf.  I am curious as to what behaviour is the default without that file.